# python function behaves differently in pyramid?

Tags: python, mechanize, pyramid

I am making webapps using python on top of pyramid framework.
In one of my function that utilize mechanize to do some simple web scraping, the function behaves differently when I run it as a standalone python script and I run it through pyramid.

Here is the mechanize function that behaves differently:

```
form = mechanize._form.ParseString(form, url)
```

I am getting Get and Post form running this function as a stand alone program, but only got Get form running it through pyramid. (python 2.7.2)

Am I missing something? Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Can you please post the code of the view and the piece of code where you assign the view to the configurator (by using `config.add_view()` and `config.add_route()`)?

Comment: I use config.add_route() and config.scan() in the __init__.py on root directory. for the view, I am using @view_config() decorator that will attach to the respective view function (same method as pyramid scaffold). Do you have any idea why this happened? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I don't use mechanize but maybe this has something to do with calling `config.scan()`. The side-effect of doing this is that it recursively imports every module in your package which could register plugins in your code with mechanize, or something along those lines.

Comment: Hi thanks for your response I just found out the problem. I read the input before I generate the form, it turns out that inside the pyramid, the string type is unicode, thus mechanize failed it. Thanks anw for your helps!

Comment: @NinoAquinas post your discovery as a separate Answer